# ASP button not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, button

So I am trying to insert a button in my company's sharepoint site with asp.  The button appears correctly, but I can't get it to go to a certain page when I click it.  When I click it it just refreshes the page.  I want it to go to this link... http://www.w3schools.com/ .  Can someone help me fix this?

```
    <WebPartPages:WikiContentWebpart frametype="none" chrometype="None" runat="server" partorder="1" __WebPartId="{9852E1FB-0E97-47D1-BC63-0A8D2D953F9D}" id="g_9852e1fb_0e97_47d1_bc63_0a8d2d953f9d">
        <content>
        <div>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add New Item" id="Button1" Font-Bold="True" onclick="window.location='http://www.w3schools.com/'"></asp:Button> </div>
        </content>
    </WebPartPages:WikiContentWebpart>
```

Comment: Is it `.net` or `asp-classic`?  It can't be both.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables classic ASP does not have those tags.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables your name reminds me of one of my favorite TDWTF stories.

Comment: @jrummell - is that good or bad? :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables very good in my book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add New Item" id="Button1" Font-Bold="True"
     OnClientClick="window.location='http://www.w3schools.com/'; return false;">   </asp:Button>
```

You need to change two things:

1. Since this is a client side handler, use `OnClientClick`.
2. Return false after setting the location so that the default event (post back) is not fired.

Comment: Also, how do I know when and when not to use return false;??

Comment: Use return false when you want to prevent the default click event. E.g. post for a button, navigate for an anchor. Also, if you found this answer helpful, please vote up and accept.

Comment: @AnotherGuy why server side control and not ordinary anchor tag?

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's a good point. If you're only redirecting to a new page, an anchor would be much simpler.

Comment: how would that look with an anchor??

Comment: @AnotherGuy this: `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Add New Item</a>` you can use CSS to make the anchor appear as a button if that's the reason you wanted a button in the first place..